# SIMPLE Ruby library for drawing shapes and managing clicks

Tags: ruby, graphics, drawing, vector-graphics

I am looking for **simple** library for Ruby that could help me drawing things on the screen. I am not developing a game, I just want to display some graphs, so I need to

- draw circles on a certain position,
- put a label on these circles,
- being notified that circle XYZ has been selected (I want to know the circle, not the coords),
- draw lines connecting circles' borders,
- change the color of the these circles,
- *(optional)* animate moving a circle from position (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) in X seconds,
- *(even more optional)* zoom on part of this scene.

Do you know anything that could help me with this?

Comment: Is your application such that you could consider opening an HTML window? If so, then you could probably do this very easily with JavaScript -- that's more or less what it's good at.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the green_shoes gem.  [Here](https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes/blob/master/samples/sample13.rb)'s an example of some code to get you started, too!